# Convert .py to .exe

Tags: python, exe, command-prompt, python-3.5, pyinstaller

How to convert python Python1.py created in Visual Studio 2015 to Python1.exe, with PyInstaller I gut error, so need to find some other tool to convert my PythonConsole.py to PythonConsole.exe

Answer (score 1):

You don't have module named pefile install the module `pip install pefile` then try again

Comment: Hello, I've edit my question after installing `pip install pefile` but I again I got error

Comment: is it the same error??

Comment: seems like it is different error. Anyway I still can't get   result with PyInstaller. I'm wondering maybe there is the other way to make executable for python console application. It is very simple code with only one import of os

Comment: do you mind pasting the error here?and the  best way i can tell is using pyinstaller,,just paste error and am sure we are going to fix this,don't give up!

Answer (score 0):

Import errors can be raised if that package is already installed. check whether that requrired package is installed, using `pip3 freeze` in the cmd/powershell.
Refer this link https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/If-Things-Go-Wrong

Comment: Hello, can't find, where is the problem by this guide. There is only one import os. Now I think maybe, I don't need .exe file and can run it   just as .py on user computer. But not sure what I must add to project, to make it work for user?